# Multilingual App, NO defined items, C#

Tags: c#, multilingual

I've been developing a [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) app. (It runs OK, there's not problem).
But Now, my boss need it work on English, Spanish and other languages.

I saw some tutorials about how to change languages in my app on different web pages ([like this](http://juank.black-byte.com/c-aplicaciones-multilenguaje-globalizacion-localizacion/), [and this](http://www.widget-101.com/codigo/localization-aplicaciones-multilenguaje-con-windows-forms/))

**My problem is:**
 I don't have defined any item, I mean, I don't have text boxes, labels or buttons. I just have a form:
While my app is running, it reads a [.txt](/questions/tagged/.txt) file: If there's a "button" line in the [.txt](/questions/tagged/.txt), my app will add a button to my form, if there's a "label" line, it will add a new label.

So, I can't use the [.resx](/questions/tagged/.resx) file as the tutorials said.
It doesn't work.

I don´t know if I'm doing it wrong or it simply doesn't work

Any idea?
I don't know what to do

I read the. txt file (line by line) and I assign the properties like this

```
public static Label[] LAB = new Label[2560];
public static int indice_LABEL = 0;


    if (TipoElemento == "LABEL")
    {
     LAB[indice_LABEL] = new Label();
     LAB[indice_LABEL].Name = asigna.nombreElemento;
     LAB[indice_LABEL].Left = Convert.ToInt32(asigna.left);//LEFT
     LAB[indice_LABEL].Top = Convert.ToInt32(asigna.top);//TOP
     LAB[indice_LABEL].Width = Convert.ToInt32(asigna.width);
     LAB[indice_LABEL].Height = Convert.ToInt32(asigna.height);
     //and all I need
     ...
     ...
     Formulario.PanelGE.Controls.Add(Herramientas.LAB[Herramientas.indice_LABEL]);
     Herramientas.indice_LABEL++;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you keep the label/button etc captions? In this text file?

Comment: @iabbott Yes. All I need is in the [tag:.txt] (name, text, size...)

Comment: Can you post a quick sample of the text file in your question, eg how you create 1 label or 1 text box

Comment: check my answer, hope it helps

Comment: if it does please mark as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to stick with this format, the best solution would be to have 1 file with all the control definitions (name, dimensions, position etc) and another with the text to display to the user

Then when you create each control, instead of assigning it a caption you use the `ResourceManager`, linked to your 'captions' files (1 for each language) to retrieve the correct string to display

For example:

**Language Text File**

This will be a simple text file, *resource.en-US.txt*

Inside, you will need to add simple key>value pairs:

```
label1=Hello world!
```

To make another language, simply create another file, *resource.fr-FR.txt*, and add:

```
label1=Bonjour le monde!
```

**Application Code**

```
// Resource path
private string strResourcesPath= Application.StartupPath + "/Resources";

// String to store current culture which is common in all the forms
// This is the default startup value
private string strCulture= "en-US";

// ResourceManager which retrieves the strings
// from the resource files
private static ResourceManager rm;

// This allows you to access the ResourceManager from any form
public static ResourceManager RM
{ 
  get 
  { 
   return rm ; 
   } 
}


private void GlobalizeApp()
{
    SetCulture();
    SetResource();
    SetUIChanges();
}
private void SetCulture()
{
    // This will change the current culture
    // This way you can update it without restarting your app (eg via combobox)
    CultureInfo objCI = new CultureInfo(strCulture);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = objCI;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = objCI;

}
private void SetResource()
{
    // This sets the correct language file to use
    rm = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager
        ("resource", strResourcesPath, null);

}
private void SetUIChanges()
{
    // This is where you update all of the captions
    // eg:
    label1.Text=rm.GetString("label1");
}
```

Then all you need to do is change the private string `strCulture= "en-US"` to "fr-FR" (eg in a combo box), and call the `GlobalizeApp()` method, and the text in `label1` will change from *Hello world* to *Bonjour le monde!*

Simple (I hope :) )

Check out [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15248/Globalization-of-Windows-Applications-in-20-Minute) for a great walkthrough

Comment: It looks useful @iabbott but, when I run it, It shows me it:
**No se encontraron recursos adecuados para la referencia cultural especificada (o para la referencia cultural neutra) en el disco.
baseName: resource  locationInfo: <null>  fileName: resource.resources** What could I do?

Comment: Did you follow the walkthrough at the link I posted?

Comment: Yes, I did @iabbott. I'll try it again. Okay? Don't worry

Comment: I still have the mistake: **Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture (or the neutral culture) on disk.
baseName: resource  locationInfo: <null>  fileName: resource.resources** What? could I do?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't done this step: **Using the Resource generator (Resgen) in the Visual Studio .NET 2003 Command Prompt, we will create three resource files which can be understood by the application**

Comment: I'm not sure if the **Command Prompt** is a 2003 version, but I did it, twice. May be the problem is the localization of the files in the "resurces" folder. This folder is in the root of my app, I mean, I have the localization.sln file, "resources" folder and "localization" folder. Should I put "resources" folder into the "localization" folder?

Comment: Yes you should have a folder with your apps .sln file, there will be another folder, go into that one, that is where the `resources` folder should go. Also that link doesn't work for me

Comment: I did it :( @iabbott **It still wrong** (You must be logged in hotmail) What about skype?

Comment: No the link is to your personal profile, I click it and get sent to my profile

Comment: **I DID IT! 
I FOUND MY MISTAKE!**
<br/> <br/> 
it was:
`rm = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager
                    ("resourceS", strResourcesPath, null);` (look the "S")


And it should be:
`rm = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager
                    ("resource", strResourcesPath, null);` <br/> <br/> 
@iabbott **thank you so much** You're amazing

Comment: No problem, glad you got there on your own :)